# Create a Stackdriver Alert Policy using gcloud? (without loading from file)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, stackdriver

So I setup a notification channel with:

```sh
gcloud alpha monitoring channels create \
    --description='test notification' \
    --display-name='test_channel' \
    --type=email \
    --channel-labels=email_address=example@gmail.com
```

But I can't seem to get an Alert Policy to work with the [command line](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/create) (trying to avoid using load from file as I would need to use a template). It seems like this should work:

```sh
gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
    --notification-channels=test_channel \
    --aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"}' \
    --condition-display-name='CPU Utilization >0.80 for 10m'\
    --condition-filter='metric.type="appengine.googleapis.com/flex/instance/cpu/utilization" resource.type="gae_instance"' \
    --duration='1min' \
    --if='> 0.80' \
    --display-name='test alert'
```

But it returns:

> Invalid value for [--aggregation]: Should only be specified if
>   --condition-filter is also specified.

However, as you can see, there's a `--condition-filter` flag above. I tried reordering it so `--condition-filter` appears before `--aggregation`, but this is causing a duration error, although it already matches the documentation, and slight edits like `=60s`, `=1min`, or adding quotes around the time in `--aggregation` doesn't seem to help:

```sh
gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
    --notification-channels=test_channel \
    --condition-filter='metric.type=appengine.googleapis.com/flex/instance/cpu/utilization resource.type=gae_instance' \
    --aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "20s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"}' \
    --condition-display-name='CPU Utilization >0.80 for 1m'\
    --duration='1min' \
    --if='> 0.80' \
    --display-name='test alert'
```

What is wrong? Why am I getting these errors?

Comment: TLDR Version of answer is I was missing combiner `--combiner='AND'`, I think I could also have done something like `--condition-filter="resource.type=\"global\" AND metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/vpc_firewall_changes\""`.
And docs got me on an incorrect `1min` formatting, when it should be `1m` which I had tried but with other errors. The flag `Channel Name: my-channel` threw me off on notification-channels, docs do mention ID but missed that and thought all flags would work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some deliberate trial an error, I managed to get this working with a few changes.

First off, I highly recommend you to use the latest Cloud SDK version - update it to the latest if you haven't already with [`gcloud components update`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/components/update). In my case, I used the Cloud SDK `v275.0.0`.

The first command snippet you provided worked correctly to create a notification channel, so that should be kept the same:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels create \
    --description='test notification' \
    --display-name='test_channel' \
    --type=email \
    --channel-labels=email_address=example@gmail.com
```

In order to create a Stackdriver Monitoring policy though, I had to perform some changes:

- The duration specified by the `--duration` flag doesn't seem to
  recognize the unit well; I had to change from `--duration='1min'` to
  `--duration='1m'` for it in order not to throw an error.
- A combiner for the Alert Policy was needed, so I added one with the [`--combiner`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/create#--combiner) option set to `AND` in this case: `--combiner='AND'`.
- The notification channel specified by the
        [`--notification-channels`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/create#--notification-channels) flag requires and `ID` or fully
        qualified identifier - it doesn't parse the display name, so I
        changed that to `--notification-channels=13234113421234567`.

  You can find the `ID` or fully qualified identifier of the
  notification channel you previously created with:

  ```
  gcloud alpha monitoring channels list \
     --filter='displayName="test_channel"' \
     --format='value(name)'
  ```

At the end, the `gcloud` command to create the Alert Policy should look similar to this:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
    --notification-channels=13234113421234567 \
    --aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"}' \
    --condition-display-name='CPU Utilization >0.80 for 10m'\
    --condition-filter='metric.type="appengine.googleapis.com/flex/instance/cpu/utilization" resource.type="gae_instance"' \
    --duration='1m' \
    --if='> 0.80' \
    --display-name='test alert' \
    --combiner='AND'
```

Note that this command is in an **alpha** state of development hence some features or functionalities may not be fully fleshed out and / or tested.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @maxim, That helped me a a lot!
Here is what i used to deploy log based metric that listens for a syslog message:

Create Log-Based Metric:

```
gcloud logging metrics create "S3-SQL-backup-failed-test2" \
    --description "The backup has failed go over the logs to find out why (tag: backup-to-s3)." \
    --log-filter "resource.type=gce_instance AND 
resource.labels.instance_id=${INSTANCE_ID} AND 
logName=projects/${PROJECT_ID}/logs/syslog AND
'SQL backup has failed failure occurred during the dump file exists validation'"
```

Create Monitor Email:

```
gcloud alpha monitoring channels create --display-name="${MONITOR_EMAIL_NAME}" /
    --type=email /
    --channel-labels=email_address="${MONITOR_EMAIL}"
```

Create Alert based on metric

```
gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
    --notification-channels="${CHANNEL}" \
    --aggregation='{"alignmentPeriod": "60s","perSeriesAligner": "ALIGN_MEAN"}' \
    --condition-display-name='S3-SQL-backup-failed-test2'\
    --condition-filter='resource.type="gce_instance" AND metric.type="logging.googleapis.com/user/S3-SQL-backup-failed"' \
    --duration='0s' \
    --display-name='Alert-S3-SQL-backup-failed-test2' \
    --if='> 0' \
    --combiner='OR' \
    --trigger-count="1"
```