# How to create log-based-metric alert (email notification) with Google Cloud SDK?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging

I know through the GCP Console it is possible to create an log-based-metric and assign it a alert policy, which can be an email notification. I'm trying to accomplish exactly that (create a log based metric tha triggers an alert that sends an email to an specific email account) BUT not from the console. Instead, with an SDK command.

So far I've this https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/metrics which helps to create the log based metric, but I can't find how to set the alert config.

Anyone knows? Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59690792/create-a-stackdriver-alert-policy-using-gcloud-without-loading-from-file

Answer (score 3):

You need to do three steps:

1. Create Log-based metric (done) [`gcloud logging metrics create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/logging/metrics/create)
2. Create Notification channel [`gcloud beta monitoring channels create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/monitoring/channels/create)
3. Create Alert policy [`gcloud alpha monitoring policies create`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/monitoring/policies/create)

Note: `gcloud beta monitoring channels` above and `gcloud alpha monitoring channels` below, you pick.

The following is lifted from one of my scripts, so I've generalized it:

```bash
PROJECT=[YOUR-PROJECT]

gcloud alpha monitoring channels create \
--display-name="..." \
--description="..." \
--type=email \
--channel-labels=email_address=your@email.com \
--user-labels=foo=bar \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Filter the list of channels by some subset of the above
# Return the name property
CHANNEL=$(\
  gcloud alpha monitoring channels list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --filter="type=\"email\" userLabels.foo=\"bar\"" \
  --format="value(name)")


# Recommend: build MQL in Console then copy-paste
FILTER="..."
AGGREGATION="..."
IF="..."

gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
--notification-channels=${CHANNEL} \
--display-name="..." \
--condition-display-name="..." \
--condition-filter="${FILTER}" \
--duration="0s" \
--aggregation="${AGGREGATION}" \
--if="${IF}" \
--trigger-count=1 \
--combiner="OR" \
--enabled \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Comment: Thanks. How can I relate the alert policy to the log based metric (SDK)?

Comment: That's a different question, please consider creating a new question if the documentation [View your log-based metrics](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics#viewing) doesn't help.

Comment: I just posted it. I'd really appreciate if you checked it as well. Thanks. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73379652/how-to-relate-a-log-based-metric-to-a-monitoring-policy