# How to relate a log-based-metric to a monitoring policy?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

Initially I was trying to accomplish what I describe in my previous question:

[How to create log-based-metric alert (email notification) with Google Cloud SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73337190/how-to-create-log-based-metric-alert-email-notification-with-google-cloud-sdk/73338084?noredirect=1#comment129585980_73338084)

Basically, only using the Google Cloud SDK commands, create a log-based-metric as well as a monitoring alert (an email sent each time a log is equal to a filter).

I know with this command I can create a log-based-metric, but after reading the documentation, can't seem to find how to relate the two functionalities so that it works as mentioned above. I know it can be easily accomplished using the Console, but in this case SDK commands are a must.

```
gcloud logging metrics create METRIC_NAME \
  --description "METRIC_DESCRIPTION" \
  --log-filter "FILTER"
```

Any idea of how to approach this problem?

Answer (score 2):

:-)

```bash
PROJECT="[YOUR-PROJECT]"

# I'm using an arbitrary log filter
# This is against the resource type `audited_resource`
FILTER="protoPayload.methodName=\"google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService\""

NAME="[YOUR-METRIC-NAME]"

# Create the log-based metric
gcloud logging metrics create ${METRIC} \
--description="Description of ${METRIC}" \
--log-filter="${FILTER}" \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Prove that it exists
gcloud logging metrics list \
--filter=${NAME} \
--format=yaml \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Yields something of the form:

```
createTime: '2022-08-16T00:00:00.000000000Z'
description: Description of foo
filter: protoPayload.methodName="google.api.serviceusage.v1.ServiceUsage.EnableService"
metricDescriptor:
  description: Description of foo
  metricKind: DELTA
  name: projects/${PROJECT}/metricDescriptors/logging.googleapis.com/user/${METRIC}
  type: logging.googleapis.com/user/${METRIC}
  unit: '1'
  valueType: INT64
name: foo
updateTime: '2022-08-16T00:00:00.000000000Z'
```

Note: The metric (!) name is `logging.googleapis.com/user/${METRIC}`. The resource type (in this case) is `audited_resource`.

Please see my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73338084/609290) for the `gcloud alpha monitoring channels create` to create an email-based notification channel. You'll need to use `gcloud alpha monitoring channels list` to get the full name of the channel to use in the next command.  It will be of the form:

```
projects/${PROJECT}/notificationChannels/12345678901234567890
```

I encourage you to use Console to create an Alerting Policy:

https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies/create

For example:

```
metric.type = \"logging.googleapis.com/user/${NAME}\"
```

Then you can "munge" (copy-and-paste-and-edit) the result into the `gcloud` command:

```bash
FILTER="
  resource.type=\"audited_resource\"
  metric.type=\"logging.googleapis.com/user/${NAME}\""
AGGREGATION="{
  \"alignmentPeriod\": \"3600s\",
  \"perSeriesAligner\": \"ALIGN_SUM\"
}"

gcloud alpha monitoring policies create \
--notification-channels=${CHANNELS}, \
--display-name="Alert for ${NAME}" \
--condition-display-name="condition-1" \
--condition-filter="${FILTER}" \
--duration="3600s" \
--aggregation="${AGGREGATION}" \
--if="> 1" \
--trigger-count=1 \
--combiner="OR" \
--enabled \
--project=${PROJECT}
```

Note: The policy is meaningless and exists just to provide an example. The value of `--notification-channels` must end in a comma (`,`) if there is only a single notification channel.

Yields:

```
Created alert policy [projects/${PROJECT}/alertPolicies/12345678901234567890].
```

You can test this example by enabling a couple of services, e.g.

```bash
gcloud services enable container.googleapis.com --project=${PROJECT}
```

And waiting for the alert to fire and send an e.g. email.

You can observe the current state of the policy in Console. See the policy created in the previous step and you'll be provided a real-time graph showing the current value of the alert and the threshold line:

https://console.cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerting/policies